# Update multiple dependencies with Bower

Tags: package, npm, updates, dependency-management, bower

I listed (and/or installed) several dependencies with Bower inside the `bower.json` file and/or with

```
bower install https://github.com/username/project.git
```

That worked fine.

Now I can list all them with

```
bower list
```

and then I can pick the name of each dependency of my project and run

```
bower update dependency-name
```

> **Question:** How can I bulk update all of them? Or do I have to write a shell script to loop through and update them?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can update all by running `bower update`.

Use the `-h` flag on any command to see how you can use it. Eg `bower update -h`.

Comment: Finally! Thanks! ... had overread the last help line that states that.

Comment: Not worked for me. The bootstrap version for example is in 3.2.0 version. I've tried do bower update bootstrap but it not updates to  3.3.0 that is the current one.

Comment: did you specify a version number in your bower.json?

Comment: Note that doing this, it will respect the versions specified in your file. If your specified Boostrap version is `~3.2.0`, it will never update to 3.3. If you want something more violent, you could use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-update-all

Comment: @Deurco How might one force an update to the latest when you have the ~ in use?

Comment: @JagWire By reinstalling the package. Simply run `bower install {package-name} --save` and the version in `bower.json` will be ignored. That is what [bower-update-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-update-all) does, for each of your packages, in one command (of course, this could break your app, since it could apply versions with breaking changes).

Comment: `-h` stands for **help**, to force update use  `--force-latest` or `-F`

Answer (score 7):

This process is a little slow but is secure because you can realize when your app gets broken.

lets say that you want to update **bootstrap** you just need to run `bower install --save bootstrap` and you bower.json file will be updated

## Before

```
 {
   "name": "my-awesome-app",
   "version": "0.0.0",
   "dependencies": {
     "bootstrap": "~3.0.0",
     "requirejs": "~2.1.11",
     "modernizr": "~2.8.2",
     "jquery": "~2.1.1",
     "underscore-amd": "~1.5.2",
     "backbone-amd": "~1.1.0",                                                                                                                                                
     "require-handlebars-plugin": "~0.8.0"
   }
 }
```

## After

```
 {
   "name": "my-awesome-app",
   "version": "0.0.0",
   "dependencies": {
     "bootstrap": "~3.3.1",
     "requirejs": "~2.1.11",
     "modernizr": "~2.8.2",
     "jquery": "~2.1.1",
     "underscore-amd": "~1.5.2",
     "backbone-amd": "~1.1.0",                                                                                                                                                
     "require-handlebars-plugin": "~0.8.0"
   }
 }
```

Comment: No, `npm install --save bootstrap` will load the latest tag of bootstrap and save it to the deps. At the time writing this it will be `"bootstrap":  "~3.2.0"`

Answer (score 2):

Used [bower-update-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-update-all) to update all bower dependencies in **bower.json**, as follows:

```
npm install -g bower-update-all
bower-update-all
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force all dependencies to update you can use `bower install --save --force`. This is the same as `bower install --save [dep1] [dep2] ...`

The short version is `bower i -S -f`